# MapServer 8 How to compile with MVT support

Tags: mapserver, compile, mapbox-vector-tile

I have compiled MapServer 8.0.0 and works well, except it will not generate an MVT tile, instead, it returns this message
`loadOutputFormat(): General error message. OUTPUTFORMAT (mvt) clause references driver (mvt), but this driver isn't configured.`

I used the following to compile

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local:/opt \
    -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=ON \
    -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=ON \
    -DWITH_CURL=ON \
    -DWITH_SOS=ON \
    -DWITH_PHP=ON \
    -DWITH_JAVA=OFF \
    -DWITH_PERL=ON \
    -DWITH_CSHARP=OFF \
    -DWITH_PYTHON=ON \
    -DWITH_RUBY=OFF \
    -DWITH_EXEMPI=ON \
    -DWITH_KML=ON \
    -DWITH_POSTGIS=ON \
    -DWITH_RSVG=ON \
    -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=0 \
    -DWITH_LIBXML2=ON \
    -DWITH_PROTOBUFC=0 \
    ../ >../configure.out.txt
```

My Mapserv -v is here

MapServer version 8.0.0 OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=RSVG SUPPORTS=ICONV SUPPORTS=XMP SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=OGCAPI_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI SUPPORTS=GEOS INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE INPUT=FLATGEOBUF

I have a MapServer 7.4.3 that does create MVT, and the only real difference I can see is that the other has SUPPORTS=PBF. (but I am not sure how to compile with PBF to test that theory).

How do I compile Mapserver 8 to support MVT tile generation?

---

I am using Ubuntu

I needed these two packages (libprotobuf-c-dev) being the one I was missing

sudo apt install protobuf-c-compiler libprotobuf-c-dev

Then it compiled like a dream with the

-DWITH_PROTOBUFC=ON

Comment: By https://github.com/sdlime/mvt-demo protobuf and protobufc are required. Maybe you are missing the protobuf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention what operating system you are referring to, but that is ok.  If you are on Ubuntu you will need to install the `protobuf-c` library with a command such as `sudo apt-get install protobuf-c-compiler`

Then, you can enable MVT support during your CMake command for MapServer, through the switch `-DWITH_PROTOBUFC=1`

Finally, you can verify that MVT support is included by executing `mapserv -v` and looking for `SUPPORTS=PBF` in the response, such as:

```
MapServer version 8.1.0-dev (MS4W 5.0.0-dev) OUTPUT=PNG OUTPUT=JPEG 
OUTPUT=KML SUPPORTS=PROJ SUPPORTS=AGG SUPPORTS=FREETYPE 
SUPPORTS=CAIRO SUPPORTS=SVG_SYMBOLS SUPPORTS=SVGCAIRO SUPPORTS=ICONV 
SUPPORTS=FRIBIDI SUPPORTS=WMS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WMS_CLIENT 
SUPPORTS=WFS_SERVER SUPPORTS=WFS_CLIENT SUPPORTS=WCS_SERVER 
SUPPORTS=SOS_SERVER SUPPORTS=OGCAPI_SERVER SUPPORTS=FASTCGI 
SUPPORTS=THREADS SUPPORTS=GEOS SUPPORTS=PBF INPUT=JPEG INPUT=POSTGIS 
INPUT=OGR INPUT=GDAL INPUT=SHAPEFILE INPUT=FLATGEOBUF
```

On Windows it is much more difficult, but good news is that I do compile MVT support into MS4W, for Windows users, to make it easy for all to use out-of-the-box : https://ms4w.com

Comment: gisinternals MapServer also supports MVT

Comment: Thanks -- this is helpful and seems to be on the right course. I must be doing something dumb. Ohh yes sorry I am on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

I have installed protobuf-c-compiler, so when I run `protoc-c --version` I get
protobuf-c 1.3.3
libprotoc 3.6.1

So it seems to be installed but can't be found on compile I get this error
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:92 (message):
  PROTOBUFC library/component/dependency could not be found.

I added
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/bin/:/usr/local:/opt
but same error.

Comment: Worked it out -- thanks for your help.  
Needed both these two packages
sudo apt install protobuf-c-compiler libprotobuf-c-dev